# Why does async work in ComponentDidMount lead to visual lag when navigating unless a simple timeOut is awaited?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, react-navigation, expo

I have a tabbed react native app and have 2 related questions:

1. Why does the navigation between screens visually lag when doing async work (such sending a network request) in the target view's `componentDidMount` method? The [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) mentions this method as the appropriate place for handling network requests but even when `componentDidMount` and the functions it calls are declared to be async () => the visual delay when initiating navigation is glaring. This visual delay occurs at the beginning of the navigation, before the target component is pushed or focused and occurs even when the async work does not modify the app state in any way that would affect the rendering of the target component.
2. Why does this visual delay disappear entirely when I await a brief timeout before doing the real async work?

```
const timeOut = t => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`Completed in ${t}`);
    }, t);
  });
};

componentDidMount = async () => { // async or not, delay occurs
  await timeOut(0); //This line prevents navigation lag
  NetworkRequest.getData(payload);
}
...

static getData = payload => {
fetch("API_ENDPOINT", {
      method: "POST",
      body: payload
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
              //process response 
       })
}
```

Whether `NetworkRequest.getData` is awaited or not, the navigation delay is present without awaiting this artificial mini-promise beforehand. I feel like I'm misunderstanding react native lifecycles or some other key part of the rendering process because I can't imagine why this little await is necessary to 'trick' the method into being visually asynchronous...

EDIT: Now that I know more about Message Queues and Job Queues, it makes sense that a potential source of the visual lag could come from jamming up the Job Queue with a large task. By awaiting a timeOut in an `async` method, that method effectively becomes the lowest-priority entity in the job queue. It seems weird screen transitions would be non-blocking since the UI is unavailable during this time, but I'm sure the react native developers had a reason... It also seems quite strange that the documentation recommends performing asynchronous work in this method when it will block without this queue relegation voodoo... Is there a better way to specify message/job queue priority on a Javascript Method beyond simple async? Or is awaiting empty timeOuts the only way to indicate lowest-priority processing.

Using expo sdk 34 which uses react-native 0.59

react-navigation 3.11

And React 16.8.3

EDIT: What a coincidence! Experimental support for Suspense for Data Fetching just announced by Dan 5 hours ago :) [More here](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html)

Comment: This question/edit pointed me in the right direction to resolve the same issue I was having.  For those with the same questions https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#:~:text=What%20is%20the%20Event%20Loop,the%20system%20kernel%20whenever%20possible.&text=js%20so%20that%20the%20appropriate,queue%20to%20eventually%20be%20executed. describes how how the "priority" (but not really) gets applied to new calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your `NetworkRequest.getData(payload)` function is doing something expensive synchronously. Because JavaScript is single threaded, the next action doesn't happen until this function returns which can cause a lag.

By adding `await timeOut(0)`, you no longer make it synchronous. It's now called in the next event loop which means any synchronous actions before that would finish already.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the clarification! I learned a bit about Event Loops in JS and I think I'm closer to understanding. By awaiting a function that goes to the Message Queue, the `async componentDidMount` gets lowest priority of any function in the Job Queue. If the Job Queue is used by React Native to animate the transition between scenes then now I have an idea why `componentDidMount` might lag transitions even when it's declared `async`.... I have edited OP to reflect more details about `NetworkRequest` and my real question

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the navigation between screens visually lag when doing async...

Maybe it can be laggy because you are on dev mode. Please try it on production.

> Why does this visual delay disappear entirely when I await a brief timeout before doing the real async work?

I'm not sure what is `NetworkRequest.getData` doing, I can be something about it,  but if it returns a promise, maybe you should try using `await` on it.

You are also forgetting to add `async` to your `componentDidMount`.

```
async componentDidMount(){
  await NetworkRequest.getData(payload);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the production mode suggestion, unfortunately the delay is still there on both prod and dev. I have also just tested awaiting NetworkRequest calls which return a promise and those with no return value and found the same lag effect occurs. Adding `await timeOut(1)` still makes things buttery smooth though... 
I've edited the OP to reflect a method that's syntactically valid :)

Comment: @user3834650 it's hard to see and know what is wrong and why that happens, but I recommend you upgrading react native and react nagivation to the latest version and see what is the problem.